# Where does Songbird stores the playlists?

Tags: music, playlists, file-location, songbird

Songbird is not working right on my machine, i'm trying to recover my playlists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Satisfaction site of Songbird](http://getsatisfaction.com/songbird/topics/where_does_songbird_save_playlists), playlists are stored in an internal database.

Thus they are only accessible via Songbird...

Comment: This answer is quite relevant since it was really easy to find the answer by a quick search. +1 for the answer but no points for the question.

Comment: It is not compatible with my songbird version (which is more modern): 1.8.0

Comment: You might want to start a new question on the Satisfaction site then, I can't help you further... :-(

Comment: @r0ca The question should get points if it's useful and clear. Given this answer is useful doesn't it turn that very clear but indeed useless question into a good one? I mean, without it you wouldn't get the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can export playlists from songbird as .m3u files using the following addon:
http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/51

Then you can use an alternative player such as MediaMonkey to scan the .m3u files and it'll recreate the playlist within its library.

Disclosure: I work on MediaMonkey

Comment: It is not compatible with my songbird version (which is more modern): 1.8.0 . 
But i found this version 2: http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1948 .
 But it doesnt work: says it cant find the export folder....
 thanks anyway